# Move files using just keyboard in Mac Finder?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, file-management

As a Windows user in previous life, I kind of miss moving files using just keyboard.

**Is this possible with in Mac OS X?**

Edit: Related problem is **navigating in finder using just keyboard** without that this really  hard. You open two windows using mouse then use keyboard is just the same as using mouse

Comment: Move as in between two folders? There must be a copy+paste function right?

Comment: After some looking I fear it won't exist (unless hacked)

Comment: Copy+paste yes, but that's *copy*, not move. I'm not at all sure if can you do cut+paste...

Comment: Looks like answer is NO :-) , With finder it is not possible!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'm answering my own question but Mac OS X Lion has it now finally. **in Lion, if you hold Option when pasting a copied Finder item (Command-Option-V), it really does move it.** (via http://tidbits.com/article/12320)

Comment: So, that's basically pressing `Cmd+C` for the files you want to cut and then `Cmd+Opt+V` in the folder you want to paste to.

Sorry, it was not clear from your answer that one should use Cmd+C and not Cmd+X

Answer (score 6):

Cmd-X doesn't work on files by default. You can enable it by executing

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AllowCutForItems 1
```

in a terminal. **But all it does it is just moving the file to trash.**

As someone said before you can move files with Cmd+dragNDrop (or just drop&drag :)), but you need mouse to do that.
Maybe there are some scripts that copies&paste and then deletes the original file? I dunno.

You may want to look for a 3rd party software, something that is equivalent to Total Commander or something like that...

Answer (score 5):

OS X does not allow that. It's an Apple Design question. They don't believe in the metaphor of "cutting" something, no matter how much *we* (users) believe in it.*1 
 So we are left with what others can come up with. And a lot of them did.

Do it with a macro in QuickSilver (which, once you know it, you wouldn't want to live without anymore anywayz): http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20081112153330648

Do it with the Context Menu (QuickAccessCM): http://www.pure-mac.com/cmm.html#quickaccesscm

Do it with a droplet (nothing I'd suggest since it uses the mouse as well): http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/27818

Do it by replacing the finder as a whole: http://www.cocoatech.com/  (Pathfinder)

I've gone the QuickSilver way, since I am a keyboard junkie and QuickSilver ... well, everything and the kitchen sink.

*1 Except that since OS 3.0 on iPhone even Apple offers a "Cut" option. I still hope - after decades of waiting - that it *will* finally be available in a Desktop OS as well...

Comment: "Cut" is always available for Text editing on most Mac apps designed by Apple. So they believe in "Cut", I guess.

Comment: we're talking about files here. not text.

Comment: read your answer you said They don't believe in the metaphor of "cutting" **something**, no matter how much we (users) believe in it."

Comment: I have answered in the context of the question. It asks "Move files using just keyboard in Mac Finder ?". I wonder why it is so important for you to point that out and lecture me about something, I haven't said. I'm sorry if I haven't answered your question to your satisfaction. I was only trying to help. Now I am sorry I did.

Answer (score 5):

use CMD + C to copy
use CMD + V to paste

OR

use CMD + ALT + V to Move (equivalent of cut and paste)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you want a Finder solution, and others have written about that, but...

You can do *hand-on-the-keyboard* manipulation of the filesystem at the command prompt (either using `Terminal.app` or an `xterm`). All the usual unix tools are availible, and in particular files are moved with

```
mv <current path>  <destination path>
```

where both paths may be either relative or absolute. If the destination is a directory (folder) the file will be put *in* the destination, otherwise the file will be renamed.

Comment: This is not mac specific. Its unix shell

Comment: @nexneo, what do you mean with your comment?

Comment: @Arjan, using command line is an option but no GUI. Its unix shell that does it. That is not mac specific interface, can be done that way in any posix compliant OS. And my question was "How to do that with Finder? " Not other application :) certainly not Non-GUI

Comment: ::looks at the title, then looks at the edit history, finally blushes:: When I wrote this I'd been perusing the existing answers and must have forgotten the title. I was thinking only in terms of a hands on the keyboard solution. It happens.

Answer (score 2):

[Cut and Paste for Finder](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/22122) is a couple of AppleScripts that appears to do the job. You'll need another add-on like Keyseer from [here](http://lonestar.utsa.edu/llee/applescript/scriptpage.html) to associate the scripts with a key combination.

Answer (score 1):

Cmd+` will cycle Finder windows.

Use the arrow keys to scroll up and down. Use Cmd+Up to go up a level.

Regular clipboard shortcuts (Cmd+X, C, V) to cut, copy, and paste.

Another useful shortcut is Cmd+Shift+/ (Cmd+?), which will let you navigate the menu bar with the keyboard.

More here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343

Comment: Like noted in earlier answers: Cmd-X won't work. The official shortcut to get to the menu bar is Ctrl-F2 (but invoking help using Cmd-? and then moving left works as well indeed).

Comment: Thanks for Ctrl+F2 -- I didn't know about that one!

Comment: Or [map Caps Lock to the menu](http://overanalyze.net/posts/2011/08/set-caps-lock-to-menu-focus-in-os-x/), like I did (self link).

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is long over and has been answered for Lion users.  But as a Snow Leopard user, the option key does not facilitate a move.  The best solution I can think of is to use the copy and paste function, and then navigate back to the copied file and use Cmd+Delete to then remove the file.

This to me seems like an excessively long way around the problem, especially if the paths between the containing folders are somewhat far apart.

Answer (score 0):

When i started using Mac OS X, i used this [website](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/)

> Copy and Paste files   Cmd-C, then Cmd-V
>   Move a file instead of copying. (Copies the file to the destination and removes it from the original disk.) Cmd-Drag file to disk

Comment: How do you do Cmd-Drag *using just keyboard* (see the question)?

Comment: Another problem is navigating in finder using just keyboard

Comment: @nexneo, I agree. For me it helped when I finally learned about Cmd-O (for opening e.g. subfolder)

Comment: Okay. after some research I found. Cmd+[ and Cmd+] shortcuts to for navigation. But still move seems like mouse only operation

Comment: If you use column view, you can pretty much navigate using only the arrow keys (and, occasionally, command).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the answer you want but you can actually do this using the keyboard, by enabling [mouse keys](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/cdb_moskys.html) in the universal access pref pane.

For example to drag a file to a window that was to the left, you would press Alt five times, then Fn-M, then hold down Cmd-Fn-U until you are in the right place, then Cmd-Fn-. and you have Cmd dragged your file.  Then press Alt five times again to turn off mouse keys.

Answer (score 0):

To move files in Finder, select and copy files with CMD C
Goto new folder
OPTION CMD V deletes copy and moves file to new location